# re-making windows-7 iso results in no ethernet controller driver

Tags: windows, networking, windows-7, virtualization, automated-install

I am making an unattended installation of Windows 7. I've gotten a bug down to this:

I start with a regular Win-7 Ultimate iso. If I install this manually on a VirtualBox virtual machine, everything works fine.

If I extract the iso to h:\win7lite, then re-make it with:

```
oscdimg -lWin7Lite -m -u2 -bh:\win7lite\boot\etfsboot.com h:\win7lite h:\result_win7lite.iso
```

(`oscdimg` gotten from WAIK), then install that... the installation finishes successfully, but the machine has no network connectivity. Not only that, it doesn't have a `Local Area Connection` set up. Not only that, but when I try to create one it says it cannot find any networking hardware. Inspecting the Device Manager shows that the Ethernet card is not working properly.

How would this extraction and re-packing break such a random thing?

I also notice it didn't ask me (on the re-made install) what network I was in (Home, Public, or Other), but it did ask me on the initial one. I'm pretty sure I changed nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Oops I used my automated script to install it from the re-made CD, which set the OS type to "Windows XP", but did it with "Windows 7" with the regular install. i believe that solves my problems